# Weird lint/compilation errors on lib.dom.d.ts - VisualStudio2017

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2017, tslint

I'm developing an Angular 4 project with VS 2017 and, from time to time, i get this huge list of lint/compilation errors.
The fact is that the mentioned file (`lib.dom.d.ts`) is not even in my project folder, but in:

```
Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.2
```

[image]